# why does not the inner 'for loop' work in the code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the code below I use two `for` loops in each other, but the inner `for` loop doesn't work and code goes to next line and check `if` and `else`.

What's wrong with the code?

```
for kk in range(1,10):
    # ---- set initial conditions (random)
    decisionE.gen = decisionE.gen * (1 + 0.2 * rand(decisionE.__len__()))
    decisionI.gen = decisionI.gen * (1 + 0.2 * rand(decisionI.__len__()))
    decisionE.V = decisionE.V + rand(decisionE.__len__()) * 2 * mV
    decisionI.V = decisionI.V + rand(decisionI.__len__()) * 2 * mV

    # ---- set initial conditions (random)
    sensoryE.V = -50.0 * mV - 2 * mV + rand(sensoryE.__len__()) * 2 * mV
    sensoryI.V = -50.0 * mV - 2 * mV + rand(sensoryI.__len__()) * 2 * mV
    sensoryE.gea = 0.05 * (1 + rand(sensoryE.__len__()) * 0.2)
    sensoryI.gea = 0.05 * (1 + rand(sensoryI.__len__()) * 0.2)

    # record spikes of excitatory neurons
    S_DE1 = SpikeMonitor(decisionE1, record=True)
    S_DE2 = SpikeMonitor(decisionE2, record=True)
    S_SE1 = SpikeMonitor(sensoryE1, record=True)
    S_SE2 = SpikeMonitor(sensoryE2, record=True)

    # record instantaneous populations activity
    R_DE1 = PopulationRateMonitor(decisionE1, bin=20 * ms)
    R_DE2 = PopulationRateMonitor(decisionE2, bin=20 * ms)
    R_SE1 = PopulationRateMonitor(sensoryE1, bin=20 * ms)
    R_SE2 = PopulationRateMonitor(sensoryE2, bin=20 * ms)

    print kk 

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Run the simulation
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # construct network
    net = Network(Dgroups.values(), Sgroups.values(), Dconnections.values(), Sconnections.values(),
                  Dnetfunctions, update_input, C_SE1_DE1, C_SE2_DE2, C_DE1_SE1, C_DE2_SE2,
                  S_DE1, S_DE2, S_SE1, S_SE2, R_DE1, R_DE2, R_SE1, R_SE2)
    net.prepare()
    net.run(runtime)

    ck_=int(runtime/20)-1

    for ii in range(1,ck_):
       if (R_DE1.rate[ii]>=15):
          break

    for jj in range(1,ck_):
       if (R_DE2.rate[jj]>=15):
          break


    if (jj>=ii):
      print R_DE1.rate[ii]
      print ("A fired at ")
      print R_DE1.times[ii]
    else:
      print R_DE2.rate[jj]
      print("B fired at ")
      print R_DE2.times[jj]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you expected to happen, but maybe this is your problem: those `break` statements will only break out of the _inner_ for loop, not the outer loop.

Comment: My guess is the inner loops are supposed to determine the first ii and jj value for which the condition is fulfilled (not the most elegant way, but it should work). So how do you know they "don't work"? What's the value of ck_, and what do ii and jj end up at?

Comment: the value of ck is 149,the loop doesn't work because it should break when R_DE1[ii] >15, but it breaks with out checking it,i checked the value of array R_DE1[ii] and print it

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood said in the comments, it looks like it's an issue regarding the `break` statements.

```
for ii in range(1,ck_):
       if (R_DE1.rate[ii]>=15):
          break

for jj in range(1,ck_):
       if (R_DE2.rate[jj]>=15):
          break
```

How often are the statements `R_DE2.rate[ii]>=15` and `R_DE2.rate[jj]>=15` true? They would stop these loops from working (assuming you meant these two loops). If the statements are true, that triggers the `break` statement and you break out of the loop and go to the next statement. [Check out what `break` does.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

I suggest replacing the `break` statements with what you want to do in those loops (these two inner loops dont do anything currently).

Comment: in the next lines of the code,the value of ii and jj cpmpared then print something,see if&else line in code

Comment: those lines won't work - you instantiated `ii` and `jj`, and they are only scoped for their respective-loops. You can re-write that code to instantiate `ii` and `jj` before their own loops, update them in the loop for when the loop breaks, then compare them?